# Where is the filesystem that "Root Storage Daemons" run on? What does it look like?

Tags: systemd, initramfs

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/RootStorageDaemons/

> ...these storage daemons are started from the initramfs, stay running all the time during normal operation and are terminated only after we returned control back to the initramfs and by the initramfs. As such, storage daemons involved with maintaining the root file system storage conceptually are more like kernel threads than like normal system services: from the perspective of the init system (i.e. systemd) these services have been started before systemd got initialized and stay around until after systemd is already gone.

But, isn't the initramfs unmounted once systemd starts?  I can't see the initramfs mounted anywhere on my Fedora 28 system.[*]

Where is the filesystem that "Root Storage Daemons" run from?

And what does it look like from their point of view?  For example, can they access a fully-featured `/dev` during runtime?

---

[*]  There is a directory `/run/initramfs`, but it is not a separate ram filesystem (tmpfs mount).  It is empty except for a couple of directories with no files, and one file `rwtab` which lists the directory names.

```
$ findmnt -T /run/initramfs
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/run   tmpfs  tmpfs  rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755
$ find /run/initramfs -type d
/run/initramfs
/run/initramfs/state
/run/initramfs/state/var
/run/initramfs/state/var/lib
/run/initramfs/state/var/lib/dhclient
/run/initramfs/state/etc
/run/initramfs/state/etc/sysconfig
/run/initramfs/state/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
/run/initramfs/log
$ find /run/initramfs -not -type d
/run/initramfs/rwtab
/run/initramfs/.need_shutdown
$ cat /run/initramfs/rwtab
files /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
files /var/lib/dhclient
$ cat /run/initramfs/.need_shutdown
$
```

Answer (score 1):

> But, isn't the initramfs unmounted once systemd starts?

No.  The initramfs filesystem [actually can't be unmounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455223/pivot-root-from-initramfs-to-new-root-error-invalid-argument/455224).

---

<del>At least if the initramfs is implemented using `systemd`, it does calls `umount()`, but it passes the flag `MNT_DETACH`.  See also `umount -l`.</del>

<del>(This mode of `umount()` is *not* prevented when there are open files.  It only "detaches" the initramfs filesystem from its mount point, removing it from the mount table (`/proc/mounts` etc).  Any open files can continue to be used.  Once all open files are closed, *then* the kernel will finish unmounting the filesystem).</del>

> Where is the filesystem that "Root Storage Daemons" run from? And what does it look like from their point of view?

The *spirit* of "RootStorageDaemons" says that they continue running inside the <del>detached</del> initramfs.

<del>In addition to detaching the mount, `MNT_DETACH` detaches any child mounts.  So Root Storage Daemons would not see critical API filesystems including /dev and /proc mounts.  This is pretty brutal:</del>

```
# unshare -m
\# umount -l /
\# findmnt
findmnt: can't read /proc/mounts: No such file or directory
\# ls /dev
\#
```

<del>After using MNT_DETACH,</del> `systemd` in the initramfs continues to match the more traditional `switch_root` command, by <del>deleting</del> unlink()ing every file from the initramfs.  (The `systemd` function is called `rm_rf_children()` - it effectively does `rm -rf *`.  As usual, any open files - including the executable and library files of running daemons - will keep working.  When the last reference to the file is closed, their storage will be freed by the kernel).

<del>If true this would be quite interesting; it would be a nice protection against a bug in a RootStorageDaemon which opened a file on the root filesystem.  It could also be a partial protection against making RPC calls through sockets in `/run`, and becoming dependent on daemons running from the root filesystem.  Doing either of these things would be liable to cause a deadlock (circular dependency).</del>

---

<del>However in *fact*, if you look at `/proc/$PID/root` of a Root Storage Daemon, it will most likely point to the main root filesystem, not the initramfs.  So why would this happen, and how does the system work in face of this?</del>

It happens because the initramfs uses `pivot_root()` to switch to the root filesystem.  As well as modifying the mount table, `pivot_root()` currently scans the root and current working directory (`/proc/$PID/root` and `/proc/$PID/cwd`) of all processes.  If either of these match the root directory of the old root filesystem (initramfs), they are replaced with the new one.  This is documented as an implementation detail of `pivot_root()`, which programs are not supposed to rely on.

`<del>`The system works because `pivot_root()` is also how `systemd` is able to switch *back* to an initramfs.  So the references to the root filesystem are replaced again, with references to the shiny new initramfs. `</del>`

---

(It is also likely that the `/run` tmpfs in the shiny new initramfs, is passed down from `/run` on the root filesystem.  Which in turn was passed down from the initramfs.  In this case, I think it would allow the shutdown initramfs to communicate with the RootStorageDaemon, if the daemon opened a socket in `/run` as part of its startup sequence.)