# pivot_root from initramfs to new root - error "Invalid argument"

Tags: linux, initramfs

> [You can not use pivot_root on an initramfs rootfs, you will get Invalid Argument. You can only pivot real filesystems.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126217/when-would-you-use-pivot-root-over-switch-root#comment435422_126222)

Indeed:

1. Fedora Linux 28 - this uses the `dracut` initramfs.
2. Boot into an initramfs shell, by adding `rd.break` as an option on the kernel command line.
3. `cd /sysroot`
4. `usr/bin/pivot_root . mnt`

-> `pivot_root` fails with "Invalid argument", corresponding to an `errno` value of `EINVAL`.

There is no explanation for this in `man 2 pivot_root`:

> `EINVAL` *put_old* is not underneath *new_root*.

Why does it fail? And as the next commenter replied, "Then how would Linux exit early user space?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unlike the `initrd`, Linux does not allow to unmount the `initramfs`.  Apparently this helped keep the kernel code simple.

Instead of `pivot_root`, you can use the `switch_root` command.  It implements the following procedure.  **Notice that `switch_root` deletes all the files on the old root, to free the initramfs memory, so you need to be careful where you run this command.**

> initramfs is rootfs: you can neither pivot_root
>       rootfs, nor unmount it.  Instead delete everything out of rootfs to
>       free up the space (find -xdev / -exec rm '{}' ';'), overmount rootfs
>       with the new root (cd /newmount; mount --move . /; chroot .), attach
>   stdin/stdout/stderr to the new /dev/console, and exec the new init.

Note the shell commands suggested are only rough equivalents to the C code.  The commands won't really work unless they are all built in to your shell, because the first command deletes all the programs and other files from the initramfs :-).

---

> Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs (or tmpfs, if that's enabled), which is always present in 2.6 systems. You can't unmount rootfs for approximately the same reason you can't kill the init process; rather than having special code to check for and handle an empty list, it's smaller and simpler for the kernel to just make sure certain lists can't become empty.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

Answer (score 3):

[From the comment on the pivot_root syscall in fs/namespace.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=4a0d11fae57989e24fe2ee3eff6d62d72db9716c):

> Also, the current root cannot be on the 'rootfs' (initial ramfs)
>   filesystem. See [Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt)
>   for alternatives in this situation.

I submitted [a patch to the man-pages project about this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/commit/?id=dc9b6c92852bca1541ed13d730b8653d2b8a806d), so in future releases of it, `man 2 pivot_root` will mention this case.